# Godot editor freezing at 66% trying to install into Android device

Tags: godot, godot4

I am trying to run a mobile game in a Android phone. It is recognized by the Godot editor and I once was able to deploy the app into the phone successfully. However, I now get always stuck at 66% of the loading process trying to install the game. I am working on a Macbook with M1 chip. Also, after this happens, I can no longer use Godot as it does not load any project, even after I force quit it. Only after restarting the computer can I use Godot again.

Is this a known bug? Is there a work around?

Comment: I tried searching on https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues but I could not find a match for the issue. So it does not appear to be a known bug. Try making a new project and deploying on the Android phone and see if it happens also. If it does, please report the issue on the given link. If it doesn't, try to discard what your project does that triggers this problem before reporting the issue.